# OpenX on Android won't fetch ads

Tags: android, mobile, openx

I'm having trouble implementing OpenX in my app. This is how I setup my OXMAdController:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //OpenX init (needs to be called before setContentView method)
    OXMManagersResolver.getInstance().prepare(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.category_pager);    

    //Setting OpenX
    try
    {
        mAdController = new OXMAdController(this, "ads.domain.com");
    }
    catch (OXMAndroidSDKVersionNotSupported e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mAdController.setAdControllerEventsListener(new OXMAdControllerEventsListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void adControllerWillLoadAd(OXMAdBaseController arg0) 
        {
            Log.v("test", "adControllerWillLoadAd");
        }

        @Override
        public void adControllerDidLoadAd(OXMAdBaseController arg0) 
        {
            Log.v("test", "adControllerDidLoadAd");
        }

        @Override
        public void adControllerDidFailWithNonCriticalError(OXMAdBaseController arg0, OXMError arg1) 
        {
            Log.v("test", "adControllerDidLoadAd");
        }

        @Override
        public void adControllerDidFailToReceiveAdWithError(OXMAdBaseController arg0, Throwable arg1) 
        {
            Log.v("test", "adControllerDidFailToReceiveAdWithError");
        }

        @Override
        public void adControllerActionUnableToBegin(OXMAdBaseController arg0) 
        {
            Log.v("test", "adControllerActionUnableToBegin");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean adControllerActionShouldBegin(OXMAdBaseController arg0, boolean arg1) 
        {
            Log.v("test", "adControllerActionShouldBegin");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void adControllerActionDidFinish(OXMAdBaseController arg0) 
        {
            Log.v("test", "adControllerActionDidFinish");
        }
    });

    mAdController.initForAdUnitIds(43, 43);
    mAdController.startLoading();
}
```

Server returns to callback method `adControllerDidFailToReceiveAdWithError` twice. First time error is `com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.errors.OXMServerWrongStatusCode: Server returned 404 status code` and second time error is `com.openx.ad.mobile.sdk.errors.OXMServerWrongResponse: Server response parsing error.`

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

First of all "ads.domain.com" is unknown domain. Is it OpenX ready server? Try to investigate demo app console logs for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to ask is where your banner? Controller is not showing anything without it. You should have something like this:

```
           @Override
            public void adControllerWillLoadAd(OXMAdBaseController c) {
                Log.w(HangApp.TAG, "adControllerWillLoadAd");
                RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_parent);
                OXMAdBannerView view = mAdController.getAdBannerView();

                if (view != null) {
                    findViewById(R.id.ad_image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0);
                    view.presentAdInViewGroup(parent, layoutParams);
                }
            }
```